# Output Datetime format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

The code below should output 18-Nov-2016.
The first messagebox outputs 18-Nov-2016
The second messagebox incorrectly outputs **18-Jan-2016**

Is the code in the first if statement correct or should i also be applying different formatting. I just happend to notice this issue when testing.

```
DateTime Output;
string Input = "2016/11/18";


if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Input, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Output))
{
 MessageBox.Show(Output.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}


if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Input, "yyyy/mm/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Output))
{
MessageBox.Show(Output.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mm` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) for minutes. [`MM` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for months.

You are using the wrong format specifier in your second `TryParseExact` method.

Since you didn't specify your month part of your `yyyy/mm/dd` format, it will be `1` by default which is January in [Gregorian calender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).

For example, your first `Output` will be;

```
18/11/2016 00:00:00
```

and that's why

```
Output.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

generates `18-Nov-2016` as a result

**but**

your second `Output` will be;

```
18/01/2016 00:11:00
```

and that's why

```
Output.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

generates `18-Jan-2016` as a result.